# зачем нужен fetch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

советуют его применять вместо $.ajax()

Comment: Детально изучить этот метод можно здесь - https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch

Comment: Как минимум затем, что не нуждается в jQuery :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это способ работы с ajax в новой версии js (es2015). 
Он позволяет делать асинхронные запросы (т.е. ajax-запросы) используя промисы (цепочку из операций, которые запустяться после того, как ajax запрос выполниться).

Очень помогает, когда запрос более-менее сложный.

Подробнее:

- https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch
- https://learn.javascript.ru/promise

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы избавиться от так называемого `callback hell`.

Посмотрите пример http://callbackhell.com/

Вспомните, когда мы посылаем запрос, мы регистрируем событие для удачного ответа от сервера и для неудачного. Внутри зарегистрированных событий могут быть другие события. И такая вложенность может быть очень большой. Код становится практически нечитабельным.

Обещания `(promises)` делают код более элегантым. И, как упомянул **Skif**, `fetch` позволяет делать запросы с использованием обещаний.